# Circumscribed Circle of an Isosceles Triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

Let $o$ be the circumscribed circle for an isosceles triangle $ABC$ with $|AB|=|AC|$. Let $D$ be a point on the side $BC$ and let $E$ be the second intersection point of the line $AD$ with $o$. I need to prove that $|AB|^2 = |AE||AD|$

[image]

Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The two triangles $ADH$ and $AFE$ are similar, so
$$
\frac{AD}{AF}=\frac{AH}{AE},
$$

or, equally: $AD\cdot AE = AH\cdot AF$.

Now, applying the first Euclid's theorem to the triangle $ABF$, you can write:

$$
AH\cdot AF = AB^2,
$$

and, by combining the two equations:

$$
AD\cdot AE = AH\cdot AF= AB^2.
$$

**Better solution:**

The two triangles $ABD$ and $ABE$ are similar, so

$$
\frac{AB}{AE}=\frac{AD}{AB},
$$

then $AB^2 = AE\cdot AD$.

Comment: What is First Euclid's theorem?

Comment: That's the italian name of the theorem: https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primo_teorema_di_Euclide I don't know what's its name in english

Comment: or we can just note that $ABD$ and $AEB$ are similar and the result follows

Comment: Oh, sure! I'll edit the solution, thanks.